# Child component not rerender after api call in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have to create a component which except one props and based on that props child component will call API and fill the dropdown. It works first time but not works in second time. API successfully called and receive the data but data not render inside the dropdown.

Here is the sample,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown';
import { fillSemester } from './../services/Dropdown';
export default class SemesterComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    _isMounted = false;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            courseInitalIndex: '',
            courseValue: [],
            semesterValue: [],
            semesterInitalIndex: '',
            semesterId: '',
            semesterName: '',
            semesterNameshort: '',
            courseId: '',
        };
    }

    async componentDidUpdate(previousProps, props) {
        if (previousProps.courseId !== this.props.courseId) {
            this.setState({
                semesterValue: []
            })
            this.getSemester(this.props.courseId, props)
        }
    }
    async getSemester(courseId) {

        var ClientId = "1";
        var TermTypeId = "2";
        var yearid = "1";
        
        const newData = {};
        newData.clientid = ClientId;
        newData.termtypeid = TermTypeId;
        newData.yearid = yearid;
        newData.courseid = courseId;

        fillSemester(newData).then(async response => {
            if (!response.status) {
                return;
            }
            var temp = [];
            for (let index = 0; index < response.dropdownlist.length; index++) {
                const element = response.dropdownlist[index];
                temp.push({
                    value: element.text,
                    id: element.value,
                    shorttext: element.shorttext
                });
            }

            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.semesterValue))
            if (temp.length > 0) {
                this.setState({
                    initalIndex: temp[0].value,
                });
            }
            this.setState({
                semesterValue: temp
            });
        });
    }
    onChangeSemester = (text, index, data) => {
        const { onChangeSemester } = this.props;
        onChangeSemester(data[index], index);
    }
    render() {
        const { text, onChangeCourse, courseId, } = this.props;
        return (
            <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
                <Text style={{ fontWeight: '700', fontSize: 12 }}>
                    SELECT SEMESTER
                </Text>
                <Dropdown
                    dropdownOffset={{ top: 3, left: 0 }}
                    rippleCentered={true}
                    data={this.state.semesterValue}
                    value={this.state.initalIndex}
                    pickerStyle={{ marginLeft: 5 }}
                    containerStyle={styles.modalDropdown}
                    inputContainerStyle={{
                        borderBottomColor: 'transparent',
                    }}
                    onChangeText={this.onChangeSemester}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }

}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    modalDropdown: {
        marginTop: 5,
        marginBottom: 10,
        height: 44,
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderColor: '#a29e9e',
        padding: 5,
    },
})


SemesterComponent.propTypes = {
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    courseId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onChangeSemester: PropTypes.func,
}

SemesterComponent.defaultProps = {
    text: 'Submit',
    onChangeSemester: () => { },
}
```

When the course changed i will update the courseId props and call the getSemester method to retrieve the data from the server using fetch. render method not called second time.

Stuck in the task from last 2 days.

Comment: Can you recreate your issue in a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)? Just add a mock for the API call, return what you expect it to return.

Comment: Can you please assign your props into the componentwillreceiveprops method. I faced the same problem and it works.

Comment: @BansariPatel Probably not ideal to suggest using deprecated react component APIs.

Comment: Jenish, the function signature for `componentDidUpdate` is `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, [snapshot])`; the current props are simply accessible in *any* lifecycle function from `this.props`. I don't think this is the issue though as `getSemester` still only consumes a single argument. If possible, can you create an [Expo snack](https://expo.io/snacks) that reproduces this issue?

Comment: if i click on that dropdown at that time i see the updated data. anything related to react-native-material-dropdown?

Comment: I suspect there may be an issue with `props.courseId` and this is why *this* component isn't updating. Have you verified that `componentDidUpdate` is *actually* called? Have you checked the previous and current prop values? Is `fillSemester` called? Have you examined the network response? Basically what debugging have you done to validate all the way up through the state update (which will trigger a rerender)?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes componentDidUpdate called on courseId props change, fillSemester and network response data is working. Even i m getting the log and also state is updated but view in not render.

Comment: Interesting. Can you try to duplicate this into an expo snack (if unfamiliar, it's a react-native online codesandbox) so that we may live debug it?

Comment: @all thank you for all your suggestion. I forgot to set this.state.initalIndex=' ' in componentDidUpdate method. Now its working as expected